# Pythonで特定条件の結果をCSVファイルに出力したい

Tags: python3

Python3系でinputで入力した内容とその各回答ごとの出現数をカウントして同時にCSVファイルに出力したいです。
CSVに入力値の出力まではできたのですが、それをどうカウントするかで詰まってます。
基礎的なPythonの文法だとは思うのですが、forなどでロジックを構築する技術が足りずご教授願えると大変嬉しいです。

【理想の出力】
NAME　COUNT
回答　　数

```
import codecs

print("Hi!I'm Roboko.What is your name ?")
name = input("")

d = {}
favor_res = input("Hey!{}!,Which restaurants do you prefer?\n".format(name))
if favor_res in d:
    d[favor_res] = d[favor_res] + 1
else:
    d[favor_res] = 1

file0 = codecs.open("/Users/apple/Downloads/practice.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8")
file0.write("NAME\tCOUNT\n")
file0.write(favor_res)
print("Thank you,{}!".format(name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

複数の回答を処理するとの事なのでループ構造を入れています(`while True: 〜`)。また、回答が無いか、空白文字類だけの場合は「無回答」をキーにして dict(辞書)に登録しています。
　質問欄にあるコードでは集計結果を `TSV(Tab Separated Values)`形式で記録しているので、回答文字列内の TAB コード(`0x09`)を `_`(アンダースコア)に変換しています(回答文字列全体を`"`(ダブルクォート)で囲んでも良いかもしれません)。

**practice.py**

```
import sys

## Greeting message
try:
    name = input("Hi! I'm Roboko. What is your name? ")
except EOFError as e:
    print(e, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

## Aggregation
d = {}
while True:
    try:
        favor_res = input(f"Hey! {name}!, Which restaurants do you prefer?\n")
    except EOFError:
        break

    favor_res = favor_res.strip()
    if favor_res == "":
        favor_res = "無回答"
        ## `continue' when ignore no answer
        # continue
    else:
        favor_res.replace("\t", "_")

    if favor_res in d:
        d[favor_res] += 1
    else:
        d[favor_res] = 1

## Write out the result with TSV format
try:
    with open("/Users/apple/Downloads/practice.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write("NAME\tCOUNT\n")
        for k, v in d.items():
            f.write(f"{k}\t{v}\n")
    print(f"Thank you, {name}!")
except IOError as e:
    print(e, file=sys.stderr)
```

**テストデータによる実行**

```
$ cat <<EOF | python3 practice.py
test
松屋
吉野家
やよい軒

富士そば
ココイチカレー
近所のレストラン

コンビニのイートイン
富士そば
EOF
```

**実行結果(practice.csv)**

```
NAME    COUNT
松屋  1
吉野家 1
やよい軒    1
無回答 2
富士そば    2
ココイチカレー 1
近所のレストラン    1
コンビニのイートイン  1
```

Comment: ものすごく参考になりました。ループ処理もそのように組み込むのですね。例外処理もやはり入れるべきみたいですね。精進します。

Comment: しかもPython3.6からformatもこんなに簡単にできたんですね。